# C# Downloading a file does not work

Tags: c#, webclient, downloading-website-files

Using code below but it is not downloading any file at all to the specified subfolder named myImages to the application... How can I fix this? The link is purely an example here, usually the link will be a variable and that has no issue populating itself. This is all being done in a BackgroundWorker that works 100% fine otherwise.

```
//File to download
string _fileToDownload = "http://www.codeproject.com/images/download24.png"
//Path to download files
string _filePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "MyImages\\download24.png'";
//Download the image
using (var webClient = new WebClient())
{
    webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(_fileToDownload ), @_filePath);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case there is no need to use asynchronous file download. This should work:

```
 webClient.DownloadFile(_fileToDownload, _filePath);
```

Comment: It doesn't want to work. I am using the code in a background worker that is already running and the minute I change it to a non async method for download, it says mthat my backgroundworker's work is completed (which is wrong since it should be working for a while longer)... this only happens with the DownloadFile method and not the ASync methiod but the ASync method doesn't download anything

Answer (score 3):

Ok. emmmmmmmmm found my answer: indeed I can use the filedownload method but it would have been useful for me to enter the correct save path... this was the correct path, I forgot to put a \ before my folder name....

```
string _filePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\MyImages\\download24.png'";
```

Comment: If this is your answer then why you accepted other one?

Answer (score 0):

So the `WebClient.DownloadFileAsync` method only creates a `Task` to download the file you need to actually start the task to download the file (by either calling `Task.Start` or `Task.RunSyncronously`) or you can call the syncronous API

```
//File to download
string _fileToDownload = "http://www.codeproject.com/images/download24.png"
//Path to download files
string _filePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "MyImages\\download24.png'";
//Download the image
using (var webClient = new WebClient())
{
    //Set the banner variable
     webClient.DownloadFile(new Uri(_fileToDownload ), @_filePath);
}
```

Comment: How could I launch the task in theory?

Comment: `webclient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(_fileToDownload ), @_filePath).Start()` should work, or if this is in an `async` method you can always just `await webclient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(_fileToDownload ), @_filePath);`

Answer (score 0):

Use the synchronous download method.

```
  webClient.DownloadFile(new Uri(_fileToDownload ), @_filePath);
```

Comment: It doesn't want to work. I am using the code in a background worker that is already running and the minute I change it to a non async method for download, it says mthat my backgroundworker's work is completed (which is wrong since it should be working for a while longer)... this only happens with the DownloadFile method and not the ASync methiod but the ASync method doesn't download anything

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code-

```
string remoteUri = "http://www.codeproject.com/images/";
string fileName = "download24.png"; 
StringWebResource = null;
// Create a new WebClient instance.
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
// Concatenate the domain with the Web resource filename.
myStringWebResource = remoteUri + fileName;
Console.WriteLine("Downloading File \"{0}\" from \"{1}\" .......\n\n", fileName,   myStringWebResource);
// Download the Web resource and save it into the current filesystem folder.
myWebClient.DownloadFile(myStringWebResource,fileName);     
Console.WriteLine("Successfully Downloaded File \"{0}\" from \"{1}\"", fileName, myStringWebResource);
Console.WriteLine("\nDownloaded file saved in the following file system folder:\n\t" + Application.StartupPath);
```

Comment: use  System.Net.WebClient.Download